# Pass non model parameter to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I pass those arguments which are not of model to a controller?

**script.rb**

```
class Script < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :directory
   attr_accessor :xmlFile
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1><%= @script.Name %></h1>

<%= simple_form_for @script, :url => script_execute_path(script_id: @script.id) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :directory %>
  <%= f.input :xmlFile %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Run' %>
<% end %>
```

Here `directory` and `xmlFile` are used for taking inputs but it is not a part of `Script` model. Now I need to pass values contained in directory and xmlFile to my `execute` controller action

```
  def execute 
    @script = Script.find(params[:script_id])
    #something like this -- @xmlFile = params[:xmlFile]
  end
```

how do I access it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are indeed part of the `Script` model, because they are defined as attributes of the model. The fact they are not persisted is irrelevant.

You access them from the hash of params that represent the model itself. You can determine the exact name inspecting the logs of the request, you'll see how the parameters are structured.

Assuming the name of the model is `Script`, the hash key that contains the script attributes should be called `script`, therefore:

```
params[:script][:directory]
```

Please note that Ruby doesn't use camelCase, therefore the name `xmlFile` doesn't follow the conventions and may cause you issues. The name should be `xml_file`, not `xmlFile`.

Comment: Yes, it's working. When do I use params[modelname][xxx] and params[xxx] ?

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary fields that aren't part of a model, you can use Rails' standalone tag helpers, such as [`text_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag):

```
<%= simple_form_for @script, :url => script_execute_path(script_id: @script.id) do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :directory %>
  <%= text_field_tag :xmlFile %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Run' %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to pre-fill them with an existing value, you can pass that in as well:

```
<%= text_field_tag :directory, 'some default value' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've actually already figured it out. By declaring

```
attr_accessor :directory
attr_accessor :xmlFile
```

in your `Script` model, you've effectively made them a part of the model. They just won't be persisted to the database when the object is saved. But as long as the object is in memory, those attributes will be available.

And since you've already got those attributes defined in your view:

```
<%= f.input :directory %>
<%= f.input :xmlFile %>
```

they'll be available to you in your controller via the `params` hash via `params[:directory]` and `params[:xmlFile]`.